# Strange behaviour in string concatenation

Tags: string, concatenation, php-5.6

This is my script.

```
$settings = [
    'amount' => "100",
    'currency' => 'AED',
 ];
 foreach($settings as $key => $val) {
   if(in_array($key,$this->supportedParams)) {
     $merchantData[] = $key.'='.$val;
   }
 }
 $merchantData = array_filter($merchantData);
 $merchantData = implode('&',$merchantData);
 print_r($merchantData);
```

The output is

> amount=100¤cy=AED

But when I change settings as

```
$settings = [
    'currency' => 'AED',
    'amount' => "100",
 ];
```

It prints correctly, which is

> currency=AED&amount=100

Why does the "currency" appear as some random characters in the first string? How can we prevent that, keeping same order for settings?

Comment: `&curren` is equal to the html entity `¤`. See https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_entities_4.asp

Comment: _Suggestion:_ Use [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) instead of doing it manually.

Answer (score 1):

PHP isn't converting anything.

The browser is converting **&currency** to **¤cy** for display purposes. If you want to see what *$merchantData* is in the browser then you will need to wrap it with htmlentities, but that specifically encodes characters so that the original *$merchantData* is displayed in the browser.

However, you should not do anything to the string *$merchantData* before passing it to hash_call.

Remember, there is a big difference between a raw string and what the browser displays.